# Can the document author restrict which parts of a document can be edited?

Tags: google-docs

I thought I read that the author could limit sections/areas of a Google Doc from being edited by others?  Maybe I was dreaming?

Comment: You're probably thinking of Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: Related: Creating fillable (?) forms?; MS Word;

Answer (score 3):

In Google Docs, you cannot limit the area of a document that an editor can edit. Anyone with editing permissions for a document will be able to edit any part of it.